# How to Convert string to byte?

Tags: java, arrays

How can I convert a String containing number like `"00110011"` to bytes using Java?
I have tried some code as follows-

```
System.Text.Encoding enc = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII; 
byte[] myByteArray = enc.GetBytes("a text string"); 
string myString = enc.GetString(myByteArray );
```

Comment: Is the number in base 2?  And you trying to do a binary conversion?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11528898/convert-byte-to-binary-in-java

Comment: That code looks like C#, not Java.

Comment: I have a feeling that what he wants from string "00110011" is to have byte array like  {0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1};

Comment: @jonasnas I want to convert an IP Address (converted to bits and then again to string) back to byte array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
int num = Integer.parseInt("00110011", 2);
byte b = (byte)num;
```

Comment: Thanks, but this one is having some limitations. I want to convert an IP Address (converted to bits and then again to string) back to byte array. Can you please help?

Comment: @PrasadPofali, I don't understand exactly. And I think you better ask another question where you provide example of input and output.

Comment: If I write byte b = Byte.parseByte("11000000",2); 
It will result in NumberFormatException : Value out of range.

Comment: @PrasadPofali, so use first snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean convert a binary number expressed as a string to an int?

If so, then:

```
String binaryString = "00110011";
int base = 2;
int decimal = Integer.parseInt(binaryString, base);
```

Comment: If binaryString is having string "11000000" it shows NumberFormatException : Value Out of range.

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this

```
String str =  "00110011";
byte[] bytes = str.getBytes();
```

Alternatively you can send an Encoding to getBytes like "UTF-16", so `str.getBytes("UTF-16")`